# laravel iterating the result from the eloquent model in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting the result like follow from model with one-to-many relationship

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"asdjash",
   "position":"jhkjh",
   "about":"hkjhkj",
   "message":"hkjhkj",
   "image":"demo.jpg",
   "status":"Active",
   "created_at":"2017-02-07 00:00:00",
   "updated_at":"2017-02-09 00:00:00",
   "personality_slider_images":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "image_name":"one.jpg",
         "personality_id":"1",
         "created_at":"2017-02-09 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2017-02-11 00:00:00"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "image_name":"two.jpg",
         "personality_id":"1",
         "created_at":"2017-02-10 00:00:00",
         "updated_at":"2017-02-26 00:00:00"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to display on page all the details

as follow

```
 <div class="well">
       <p><h4>Name : </h4> 
       {{ $personality->name }}
       </p>
       <p><h4>Position : </h4> 
       {{ $personality->position }}
       </p>
       <p><h4>About : </h4> 
       {{ $personality->about }}
       </p>
       <p><h4>Image : </h4> 
       <img src="{{ URL::to('/contents/personality/' . $personality->image) }}" alt="{{ $personality->image }}" width="150" height="180"  style="display: block; ">                      
       </p>
       <p><h4>Message : </h4> 
       {{ $personality->message }}
       </p>
       <p><h4>SliderImage : </h4> 
       {{ $personality }}

       </p>
       <p><h4>Status : </h4> 
       {{ $personality->status }}
       </p>
 </div>
```

I have tried this

```
@foreach($personality->personality_slider_images as $p)
  {{ $p->image_name }}
@endforeach
```

But it gives error as follow

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Can anyone please help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you show how you got `$personality` and the relations in model? foreach requires an argument to be an array or collection. make sure `$personality->personality_slider_images` gives an array or collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have got json array,

1. Decode it using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

   `$decode = json_decode($encode);`
2. Now traverse your loop as,

   @foreach($personality->personality_slider_images as $p)

   {{ $p->image_name }}

   @endforeach

It will work.

Give it a try.

Comment: thank you. it works. need suggestion for "should I need to proper format the result returned from the model like in totally in array or JSON,if yes then how i should approach it."thanks

Comment: You're most welcome first. And second, if you need pure array then json_decode($your_arr, true); here true returns associative array, but as said, everything is made for a reason, you see your requirement, and use that function  as you want. means you can do it either way around.

Answer (score -2):

You should add a for each for your actual array, not for a variable in that array.

Assuming your array name is $personalities, it should look like this.

```
@foreach ($personalities as $personality)
Insert the HTML from your sample above in here. 
@endforeach
```

To retrieve the image object you would have to do something like the following

```
$personality->personality_slider_name['image_name]
```

Comment: Op has posted the returned data. $personality is not an array. So having a foreach on $personality doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @VinitSarvade it indeed solves the problem because this person is trying to loop through an object sitting within the array which won't work unless that object was also an array with many objects which personality_slider_images is not. I have just shown them how to properly loop through the object and then additionally how to retrieve variables from personality_slider_images.

Comment: But I do not see where the $personality is within an array. You can clearly see that personality is an object and array. Whereas the value for personality_slider_images is an array.